# many to many intersection tables in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How is the best way to do something similar to many to many cardinality tables in ordinary sql.

Example - Three tables: Product(id identity, name varchar(max)), Sale(id identity,customer varchar(max)), SalesLine(id identity, product integer references product, sale integer references sale):

```
INSERT INTO Product (name) VALUES ('new product');
INSERT INTO Sale (customer) VALUES ('new customer');
INSERT INTO SaleLine(product, sale) VALUES(?,?);
```

In postgresql things like `currval` is helpful but this is not available in amazon redshift.

I'm thinking that maybe some other paradigme is needed?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK redshift doesn't support insert returning/currval/something similar. you can see this in Amazon redshift forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=449390

In case you have a serial insert (not from multiple threads) my suggestion is not to use Identity column but to maintain a pk and a ref table with high value and to specify IDs yourself.

P.S this solution also works with parallel insert it just a little trickier.